# Bootstrap Equivalent used in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap I have used this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        Item 3
    </div>
</div>
```

and thats it. I can create a very responsive 3 column row.

How about in WooCommerce WordPress? all I made is this.

```
<p class="form-row">
    <div class="u-column2 col2-set">
        <div class="u-column1 col-1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="u-column2 col2-set">
        <div class="u-column1 col-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
```

Is there any way to handle this kind of class? Can I make same as in bootstrap? If no what is the bootstrap equivalent in WooCommerce?

Comment: it is depending on your WooCommerce WordPress theme

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is to use Bootstrap CSS styling functions.

What I would recommend is copying the following lines of code : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css
to a new .css file,say you name it bootstrap-copy.css. And then finally, use wp_enqueue_style ( 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/ ) to add bootstrap-copy.css and then use the bootstrap classes with ease.